# CoffeeScript support by visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, syntax-highlighting, coffeescript

for coffee script in visual studio currently I'm using [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) plugin. But on relatively small script it works really slow. Are there other VS plugins with better performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chirpy also supports CoffeeScript: http://chirpy.codeplex.com/. I can't guarantee it performs better though.

Comment: I'd advise against this one, it seems to be pretty buggy, and it [doesn't have any kind of uninstaller](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/workitem/119).